# tf.data.Dataset.padded_batch pad differently each feature

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I have a `tf.data.Dataset` instance which holds 3 different features

- `label` which is a scalar
- `sequence_feature` which is a sequence of scalars
- `seq_of_seqs_feature` which is a sequence of sequences feature

I am trying to use `tf.data.Dataset.padded_batch()` to genereate padded data as input to my model - and I want to pad every feature differently.

Example batch:

```
[{'label': 24,
  'sequence_feature': [1, 2],
  'seq_of_seqs_feature': [[11.1, 22.2],
                          [33.3, 44.4]]},
 {'label': 32,
  'sequence_feature': [3, 4, 5],
  'seq_of_seqs_feature': [[55.55, 66.66]]}]
```

Expected output:

```
[{'label': 24,
  'sequence_feature': [1, 2, 0],
  'seq_of_seqs_feature': [[11.1, 22.2],
                          [33.3, 44.4]]},
 {'label': 32,
  'sequence_feature': [3, 4, 5],
  'seq_of_seqs_feature': [[55.55, 66.66],
                           0.0, 0.0    ]}]
```

As you can see the `label` feature should not be padded, and the `sequence_feature` and `seq_of_seqs_feature` should be padded by the corresponding longest entry in the given batch.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The `tf.data.Dataset.padded_batch()` method allows you to specify `padded_shapes` for each component (feature) of the resulting batch. For example, if your input dataset is called `ds`:

```
padded_ds = ds.padded_batch(
    BATCH_SIZE,
    padded_shapes={
        'label': [],                          # Scalar elements, no padding.
        'sequence_feature': [None],           # Vector elements, padded to longest.
        'seq_of_seqs_feature': [None, None],  # Matrix elements, padded to longest
    })                                        # in each dimension.
```

Notice that the `padded_shapes` argument has the same structure as your input dataset's elements, so in this case it takes a dictionary with keys that match your feature names.